# I need a way to implement the function matches() from XPath 2.0 with functions from XPath 1.0

Tags: regex, xpath, match

I have the following piece of code:

root="//valueExpression[matches(self::*,'pattern')]/.."

But I can only use XPath 1.0 and I get an exception for the function matches(). Can you please help me with a solution using only functions from XPath 1.0 ?

Comment: Good question (+1). See my answer for explanation and ways for a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

**Generally, this can't be done just using XPath 1.0**.

However, there is a set of standard XPath 1.0 functions that you can use for string processing:

- `substring()`
- `substring-before()`
- `substring-after()`
- `translate()`
- `normalize-space()`
- `string-length()`
- `count()`

Comment: I know these functions... but somehow I need a solution... if anyone can help.

Comment: @Jenny-Smith: There's no way to have the function `matches()` in XSLT 1.0 unless you implement it yourself as an extension function. If you can do with something "similar" but not exactly the same, consider using the RegEx module of EXSLT -- if your XSLT processor implements EXSLT, it may implement the RegEx module. If you need XPath nor hosted in XSLT, then only the first option remains.